# Integration by parts: Am I doing this right?

Tags: calculus, integration

So I'm working through the problems in [this book](https://doi.org/10.1017/9781316995433). While I'm not at school, I can totally see how this might be someones homework, so if I have made any egregious errors in anything outside of the specific question, be a sport and don't blurt it out.

I should stress, I haven't taken a calculus course in (>10) years, and even when I did, I only passed by the thinnest of margins. Possibly a rounding error on the school system.

Anyway, I dug up my old books, and am using *integration by parts* to evaluate this equation
$$
\left<x^2\right> = \sqrt{\frac{\lambda}{\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}{x^2 e^{-\lambda(x-a)^2}}dx.
$$

I start by dusting of my [calculus textbook](https://www.pearson.com/uk/educators/higher-education-educators/program/Adams-Calculus-A-Complete-Course-6th-Edition/PGM767211.html), turn to page 316 to find this helpful integration rule/strategy:
$$\int{U(x)\frac{dV}{dx}}dx = U(x)V(x) - \int{V(x)\frac{dU}{dx}}dx.$$

I won't bore you with all the details, but after a little massaging I get the equation down looking like this:
$$
\left<x^2\right> = \sqrt{\frac{\lambda}{\pi}} \Big[
        \overbrace{x^2}^{U(x)} \cdot \overbrace{e^{-\lambda (x-a)^2}}^{V(x)} - 
          \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}{
            \overbrace{e^{-\lambda (x-a)^2}}^{V(x)} \cdot 
            \overbrace{e^{-\lambda (x-a)^2} \cdot -2\lambda (x-a)}^{\frac{dV}{dx}}
           }dx
\Big].
$$

*(Let's just ignore any errors I may have made in applying the chain rule or using a poor substitution strategy or anything of that nature)*

Now I was surprised to find the integral on the right hand side is actually not so hard to evaluate (it only took me a week of bugging the chat room to nut out). But now I am left scratching my head about how I evaluate the functions on the left, namely $U(x)$ and $V(x)$.

But then I realized, typing up this post, the rule is for an indefinite integral, I am evaluating a definite integral. So I just need to evaluate the functions at the endpoints, ie what is missing is:

$$
\left<x^2\right> = \sqrt{\frac{\lambda}{\pi}} \Big[
        {x^2} \cdot e^{-\lambda (x-a)^2} - 
          \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}{
            {e^{-\lambda (x-a)^2}}\cdot 
            e^{-\lambda (x-a)^2} \cdot -2\lambda (x-a)
           }dx
\Big] \Big|_{-\infty}^{+\infty}
$$

Am I on the right track there?

**Edit:**

From `@David K`'s comment I think what I meant was. I'm not really familiar with typing out an integral mid-evaluation.:
$$
\left<x^2\right> = \sqrt{\frac{\lambda}{\pi}} \Big[
        \big({x^2} \cdot e^{-\lambda (x-a)^2}\big)\ \Big|_{-\infty}^{+\infty} - 
          (-2\lambda) \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}{
            (x-a) e^{\lambda^2 (x-a)^4}
           }dx
\Big]
$$

Comment: As written, you have applied the limits $-\infty,\infty$ to the integral twice, which I think defeats the purpose; but assuming that what you *meant* to do was to apply the brackets $[\cdots]_{-\infty}^\infty$ to the part outside the integral and evaluate the definite integral just once, you're on the right track; I think this is what lmv's answer says.

Comment: I have rewritten the last equation to match what I think the right answer is (based on @Imv's answer). Would you interpret the placement of the limits to now only apply to the left side functions?

Comment: Yes, the revised notation looks good. It says exactly what I think you wanted to say.

Comment: However you got to $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}{(x-a) e^{\lambda^2 (x-a)^4}}dx$ is suspect, because of the $\lambda^2(x-a)^4$ in the exponential. That integral is divergent, but its Cauchy Principal Value is $0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general rule for integration by part is understood more easily as follows. For two functions $u$ and $v$, consider there derivatives $u'$ and $v'$ and a range of integration between $a$ and $b$ both finite. Then:

$$\int\limits_{a}^b u'(x) v(x) dx = u(b)v(b) - u(a)v(a) - \int\limits_{a}^b u(x)v'(x) dx$$

Now for $a$ and/or $b$ infinite, take a limit. This should be enough to set you on the right tracks.

Comment: Thanks @Imv: I took the limits of the functions $u(x)v(x)$ at $\pm\infty$ and go to 0. So the left portion, is 0. The integral on the right is tricky to evaluate, so I plotted the function, and noticed it is symetric around the origin, suggesting that the integral also goes to 0. But I don't expect $<x^2>$ to be 0, what am I doing wrong? Did I make a mistake earlier up the chain perhaps?

Comment: @Andrew A plot that is symmetric about the y-axis gives an even function : $f(x) = f(-x)$. So you can reduce your integral over the real line to twice the integral over the positives reals. If $f(x)=-f(-x)$, then your function is odd, and indeed, the integral over a symmetric interval, e.g. the whole real line, is zero.

Answer (score 1):

A nice thing that you have as well is:
$$\int V\frac{dV}{dx}dx=\int VdV=\frac{V^2}{2}+C$$

Comment: Does this nice thing have a name?

Comment: Its basically just chain rule @AndrewMicallef

Answer (score 1):

In the line that reads
$$
<x^2> = \sqrt{\frac{\lambda}{\pi}} \Big[
        \overbrace{x^2}^{U(x)} \cdot \overbrace{e^{-\lambda (x-a)^2}}^{V(x)} - 
          \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}{
            \overbrace{e^{-\lambda (x-a)^2}}^{V(x)} \cdot 
            \overbrace{e^{-\lambda (x-a)^2} \cdot -2\lambda (x-a)}^{\frac{dV}{dx}}
           }dx
\Big]
$$
The integral is supposed to be $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}V(x)\frac{\mathrm{d}U}{\mathrm{d}x}\,\mathrm{d}x$, not $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}V(x)\frac{\mathrm{d}V}{\mathrm{d}x}\,\mathrm{d}x$

---

This integral is simplified a whole lot using $y=x-a$, giving
$$
\sqrt{\frac\lambda\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}(y+a)^2e^{-\lambda y^2}\,\mathrm{d}y
$$
Expanding $(y+a)^2=y^2+2ay+a^2$ gives a sum of three integrals, one of which is
$$
\sqrt{\frac\lambda\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}y^2e^{-\lambda y^2}\,\mathrm{d}y
$$
where you can use Integration by parts with $U(y)=-\frac{y}{2\lambda}$ and $V(y)=e^{-\lambda y^2}$. This gives $\frac{\mathrm{d}V}{\mathrm{d}y}=-2\lambda y\,e^{-\lambda y^2}$. Furthermore,
$$
\sqrt{\frac\lambda\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}U(y)\,\frac{\mathrm{d}V}{\mathrm{d}y}\,\mathrm{d}y=\sqrt{\frac\lambda\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}y^2e^{-\lambda y^2}\,\mathrm{d}y
$$
One of the other two integrands is odd, and the final one is kind of well-known.